# Wordpress Hook the_content Within Widget

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget

I am writing a widget that list the headings in the post and then created hash links and edits the HTML to reflect that. I've got the list widget content figured out and I just need to edit the_content, i've tried to add a filter for the method that returns the updated code but it's not working.

What would be the best way to do this? My class is called `post_headings_widget` and the edited HTML content is stored within `$this->the_content`.

I was hoping I could do this within the widget class

```
public
function edited_content() {
    return $this->the_content;
}
```

and then to edit the content output here

```
add_filter( 'the_content', [ 'post_headings_widget', 'edited_content' ] );
```

It calls the class method fine but i'm not sure exactly how it works so i'm guessing it called the method directly without calling the constructors etc?

I have also tried to just create a filter from within the `widget()` method but that did not work either, heres what I tried:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function() {
    return 'test';
} );
```

Any ideas on a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `the_content` as a parameter in your filter function/callback.

Check the Wordpress docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Answer (score 0):

On widgets you need to bind on [widget_text](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/widget_text/)

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'se24265_my_function');

function se24265_my_function( $content )
{
# replace code here on widget $content
return $content;
}
```